# Java HashMap iterate through for each loop but all the values are same being the last value of a loop

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have a problem using Java HashMap API. I iterate through the loop and then insert key and values to the HashMap. I also check the values before insert to hashmap all exist correctly. after then I print the hashmap, there is same values are printed finally.but all are the last value of the above loop. Below is the code:-

```
    Map<String,Map<String,StockReOrderLevel>> stockReorderLevels = new HashMap<>();
    List<StockReOrderLevel> defaultStockItemList = db.findDefaultStockItem();
    List<String> orderedItemCodes=new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, StockReOrderLevel> itemMap = new HashMap<>();

    defaultStockItemList.forEach(item-> {
        orderedItemCodes.add(item.getCode());
        itemMap.put(item.getCode(), item);
    });

    outletList.forEach(outletCode->{

        Map<String, StockReOrderLevel> clone = (Map<String, StockReOrderLevel>) ((HashMap<String, StockReOrderLevel>) itemMap).clone();
        List<OutletItem> lastStockTakenForOutlet = db.findLastStockTakenForOutlet(outletCode);

        if(lastStockTakenForOutlet!=null && !lastStockTakenForOutlet.isEmpty()){
            lastStockTakenForOutlet.forEach(outletItem -> {

                if (clone.containsKey(outletItem.getItemCode())) {
                    StockReOrderLevel stockReOrderLevel = clone.get(outletItem.getItemCode());
                    stockReOrderLevel.setReorderlevel(outletItem.getReorderLevel());
                    clone.put(outletItem.getItemCode(),stockReOrderLevel);
                }
            });

            //get database values
            Map<String,Object> paramMap=new HashMap<>();
            paramMap.put("outletCode",outletCode);
            paramMap.put("takenDate",lastStockTakenForOutlet.get(0).getTakenDate());
            List<ItemLevel> reOrderedLevelOutletItems=db.findTotalOrderdBottlesByOutlet(paramMap);

            //change the clone again
            if(reOrderedLevelOutletItems!=null && !reOrderedLevelOutletItems.isEmpty()){
                reOrderedLevelOutletItems.forEach(itemLevel -> {

                    if (clone.containsKey(itemLevel.getItemCode())) {

                        StockReOrderLevel stockReOrderLevel = clone.get(itemLevel.getItemCode());
                        stockReOrderLevel.setReorderlevel(stockReOrderLevel.getReorderlevel()+itemLevel.getAmount());

                        clone.put(itemLevel.getItemCode(),stockReOrderLevel);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //convert map and it gives the map correctly
        Map<String,StockReOrderLevel> idlOrdered= getIndexedItemOrder(orderedItemCodes,clone);

        //i printed values before add to parent map in here
        stockReorderLevels.put(outletCode, idlOrdered);
    });
    return stockReorderLevels;
```

Comment: Did you try to Debug the key-value pairs which are being updated in the corresponding _HashMap_?

Comment: yes. i debug key and value pairs before put into the parent map.all are works fine. but after returned parent map repeated with last value.

Comment: If you're debugging it properly then it shouldn't behave like that. Well, would you put some debug statement & check the values in each & every iteration whether the values are getting updated in _HashMap_ or not?

Comment: i used simple `sout` statement and i print the values each iteration.it received the correct different values for me. but after put all to the parent map, then i check that whole parent map using another `sout`.all values are repeated!

Comment: Why are you cloning the `itemMap`? You do neither add nor remove mappings, so cloning is unnecessary

Comment: @ThomasKläger yeah.actually you right.but i used it for another purpose which isn't mentioned above code.do you think is it the cause for that repeating?

Comment: It very much depends on what `getIndexedItemOrder()` does. Basically you have one group of `StockReOrderLevel` items and you change these on each loop iteration.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I removed the clone and run again.but issue still exists!

Comment: Assume that `db.findDefaultStockItem()` returns a list containing one `StockReOrderLevel` object. Through all your loops you never create a copy of this `StockReOrderLevel` object. That means that in the end all entries in `stockReorderLevels` reference the same `StockReOrderLevel` object. If you expect the entries in `stockReorderLevels` to have different `StockReOrderLevel` objects you have to create new `StockReOrderLevel` objects yourself.

Comment: @ThomasKläger ok.finally you solved my problem.Thanks for it.but now another problem.when i call to database through a loop it has performance problem.is not it?

Comment: The final answer is stated below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the answer is resolved by @ThomasKläger. i insert the defaultStockItem into the loop and the edited code is here.

```
Map<String,Map<String,StockReOrderLevel>> stockReorderLevels = new HashMap<>();


outletList.forEach(outletCode->{

List<StockReOrderLevel> defaultStockItemList = db.findDefaultStockItem();
List<String> orderedItemCodes=new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, StockReOrderLevel> itemMap = new HashMap<>();

defaultStockItemList.forEach(item-> {
    orderedItemCodes.add(item.getCode());
    itemMap.put(item.getCode(), item);
});

    Map<String, StockReOrderLevel> clone = (Map<String, StockReOrderLevel>) ((HashMap<String, StockReOrderLevel>) itemMap).clone();
    List<OutletItem> lastStockTakenForOutlet = db.findLastStockTakenForOutlet(outletCode);

    if(lastStockTakenForOutlet!=null && !lastStockTakenForOutlet.isEmpty()){
        lastStockTakenForOutlet.forEach(outletItem -> {

            if (clone.containsKey(outletItem.getItemCode())) {
                StockReOrderLevel stockReOrderLevel = clone.get(outletItem.getItemCode());
                stockReOrderLevel.setReorderlevel(outletItem.getReorderLevel());
                clone.put(outletItem.getItemCode(),stockReOrderLevel);
            }
        });

        //get database values
        Map<String,Object> paramMap=new HashMap<>();
        paramMap.put("outletCode",outletCode);
        paramMap.put("takenDate",lastStockTakenForOutlet.get(0).getTakenDate());
        List<ItemLevel> reOrderedLevelOutletItems=db.findTotalOrderdBottlesByOutlet(paramMap);

        //change the clone again
        if(reOrderedLevelOutletItems!=null && !reOrderedLevelOutletItems.isEmpty()){
            reOrderedLevelOutletItems.forEach(itemLevel -> {

                if (clone.containsKey(itemLevel.getItemCode())) {

                    StockReOrderLevel stockReOrderLevel = clone.get(itemLevel.getItemCode());
                    stockReOrderLevel.setReorderlevel(stockReOrderLevel.getReorderlevel()+itemLevel.getAmount());

                    clone.put(itemLevel.getItemCode(),stockReOrderLevel);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //convert map and it gives the map correctly
    Map<String,StockReOrderLevel> idlOrdered= getIndexedItemOrder(orderedItemCodes,clone);

    //i printed values before add to parent map in here
    stockReorderLevels.put(outletCode, idlOrdered);
});
return stockReorderLevels;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get the last element repeating when printing after a for loop it's almost certainly due to not declaring new variables (and thus not new memory). For example :

```
    List <Integer[]> arrayOuter = new ArrayList <> ();
    Integer[] array = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //shuffle array    
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));

        //add array to arraylist
        arrayOuter.add(array);
    }
```

If the last result of the shuffle was {4, 2, 1, 3}, it would print {4, 2, 1, 3} 4 times because I declared the array being inserted once and therefore all elements are pointing to one array (and each iteration overwriting the previous iteration). The correct way would be to declare a new array in each iteration of the loop, like so :

```
    List <Integer[]> arrayOuter = new ArrayList <> ();


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
        //shuffle array    
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));

        //add array to arraylist
        arrayOuter.add(array);
    }
```

One other culprit I can think of is that your key, outletCode remains the same and you are overwriting your previous (key, value) every iteration of the loop.

Comment: That is strange. From what I can see in the code you have posted the only reason why you are getting the last value repeating is because you are referencing the same memory location and not creating new elements. I have updated my answer above for a possible other culprit.

Comment: thanks for your response.i understood your solution. but can you see i do the same thing above that you say. my parent map is `stockReOrderLevels` which declared outside of for each loop. i used the clone of `itemMap` inside the for each loop.so it works as your answer.as well as i checked about the outlet codes.all are different!